# I failed to create obj file in Flutter desktop embedding project (on visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, flutter

I'm trying to build flutter desktop embedding example project
(https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding)

I stuck on fail to create some obj files

I tried to include folder (flutter_desktop_embedding\library\include)
and other "include" folders. but still keep failing.

here are the log

```
1>Run the embedder library's GN build
1>Done. Made 14 targets from 12 files in 16ms
1>ninja: Entering directory `E:\flutter_desktop\flutter_desktop_embedding\example\windows_fde\scripts\..\..\..\out'
1>[1/41] CXX obj/library/common/client_wrapper/src/client_wrapper.engine_method_result.obj
1>FAILED: obj/library/common/client_wrapper/src/client_wrapper.engine_method_result.obj
1>vcvars64.bat 1> nul && cl /nologo /showIncludes /MDd /FC -DUSE_FDE_TREE_PATHS -I../library/include -I.. -I../library/common/client_wrapper/include -I../third_party/jsoncpp/src/include /EHsc /W3 /Od  /c ../library/common/client_wrapper/src/engine_method_result.cc /Foobj/library/common/client_wrapper/src/client_wrapper.engine_method_result.obj /Fdobj/library/common/client_wrapper/client_wrapper_c.pdb
1>CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
1>[2/41] CXX obj/library/common/client_wrapper/src/client_wrapper_internal.json_message_codec.obj
1>FAILED: obj/library/common/client_wrapper/src/client_wrapper_internal.json_message_codec.obj
1>vcvars64.bat 1> nul && cl /nologo /showIncludes /MDd /FC -DUSE_FDE_TREE_PATHS -DFLUTTER_DESKTOP_EMBEDDING_IMPL -I../library/include -I.. -I../library/common/client_wrapper/include -I../third_party/jsoncpp/src/include /EHsc /W3 /Od  /c ../library/common/client_wrapper/src/json_message_codec.cc /Foobj/library/common/client_wrapper/src/client_wrapper_internal.json_message_codec.obj /Fdobj/library/common/client_wrapper/client_wrapper_internal_c.pdb
1>CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an include path problem; the `system cannot find the file specified` error is while trying to launch the process.

Either you don't have `vcvars64.bat` in your path [as described in the setup instructions](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/library/README.md#visual-studio-command-line), or you don't have `cl.exe` installed.

To figure out which problem you have, run `tools/run_dart_tool doctor`. It will tell you whether `vcvars64.bat` is in your path.